# Upgrading CiviCRM under Drupal 8: How can I get around this error?

Tags: upgrade, drupal-8, composer

I'm guessing that the upgrade process for CiviCRM under Drupal 8 is something like this:

1. Use `composer require` to get the latest version of the package.
2. Navigate to the database update URL through the browser (http://example.org/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1)

But trying this now, I see what appears to be a version conflict around the pear/log package:

```
$ composer require --update-with-dependencies civicrm/civicrm-core:5.28.3
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.8 requires pear/pear_exception v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by pear/pear_exception[v1.0.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.8 requires pear/pear_exception v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by pear/pear_exception[v1.0.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 8.8.8 requires pear/pear_exception v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by pear/pear_exception[v1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: pear/pear_exception[v1.0.1, v1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: pear/pear_exception[v1.0.1, v1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: pear/pear_exception[v1.0.1, v1.0.0].
    - pear/log 1.13.2 requires pear/pear_exception 1.0.1 -> satisfiable by pear/pear_exception[v1.0.1].
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.28.3 requires pear/log 1.13.2 -> satisfiable by pear/log[1.13.2].
    - Installation request for civicrm/civicrm-core 5.28.3 -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-core[5.28.3].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended (locked at 8.8.8, required as ^8.8) -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.8.8].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I get around this problem and upgrade CiviCRM under Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

(confirming this syntax)

```
karins-MBP:d8civicrm.local sysadmin$ composer require pear/pear_exception:'1.0.1 as 1.0.0'
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
  - CiviCRM asset map
30 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

Syntax in
https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/
is wrong. Will put in an MR -> https://lab.civicrm.org/documentation/docs/installation/-/merge_requests/10

Comment: KarinG, looks like the correct command is `composer require pear/pear_exception:"1.0.1 as 1.0.0"` (note colon, quotation marks, and `pear/pear_exception` instead of `pear/exception`). Do you think it's worth editing the answer?

Comment: For reference, this worked for me: `composer require pear/pear_exception:"1.0.1 as 1.0.0";  
composer require --update-with-dependencies civicrm/civicrm-core:5.28.3 civicrm/civicrm-drupal8:5.28.3;
cv up:db;`